# R Markdown does not run

Tags: r, r-markdown

I tried to run my script in R Markdown. It does not run and gives the error below:

Quitting from lines 15-139 (m.Rmd) 
Erro em `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "efavirens", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 5794
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execu��o interrompida

The following is a part of the script:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
suicidio <- read.csv2("E:/Spss/suicidio4.csv",header=T,sep=";")

str(suicidio)

suicidio<-subset(suicidio,desfecho != 9)
suicidio2<-subset(suicidio,Desfecho2 != 9)

suicidio$tempo<-as.numeric(suicidio$tempo)
suicidio$dias_inicio[suicidio$dias_inicio_cont == "#NULO!"]<-NA
suicidio$dias_fim[suicidio$dias_fim_cont == "#NULO!"]<-NA
suicidio$cor[suicidio$A19_COR == "#NULO!"]<-NA
suicidio$sexo<-factor(suicidio$sexo)
suicidio$cor<-factor(suicidio$cor)
suicidio$obito<-factor(suicidio$obito)
suicidio$escol2<-factor(suicidio$escol3)
suicidio$idade_hiv_cat<-factor(suicidio$idade_hiv_cat2)
suicidio$idade_hiv_cat<-factor(suicidio$idade_dtfim_cat)
suicidio$acomp_regular<-factor(suicidio$acomp_regular)
suicidio$drogas<-factor(suicidio$drogas)
suicidio$alcool<-factor(suicidio$alcool)
suicidio$efavirens<-factor(suicidio$efavirens)
suicidio$epilepsia<-factor(suicidio$epilepsia)
suicidio$tentativa<-factor(suicidio$tentativa)
suicidio$causa_externa<-factor(suicidio$causa_externa)
suicidio$causa_externa<-factor(suicidio$transgen)
suicidio$causa_externa<-factor(suicidio$cate_expo2)
suicidio$causa_externa<-factor(suicidio$etnia
````

)

```
library(survival)

y<-Surv(suicidio$tempo,suicidio$desfecho)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted answer (if not, feel free to comment)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a R Markdown error, this is an R error, telling you that you have a bug in your R code. Run the script line by line (CTRL+Enter is a good shortcut) and see which one gives the error. It is basically saying that you are trying to overwrite a column with 5794 cells/rows with a vector that has no data in it (something where `length(x)` would yield 0; printing the object would report factor(0) or character(0), or whatever the data type).